# Display filtered list by category

Tags: 2013, list, caml-query, filter, query

The current script **creates a table** showing all Items from the list.

e.g. In my list there is a column named 'Category' with 'Cats' and 'Dogs'.

What I want to achieve is to FILTER and ONLY display 'Category' with 'Cats' **in the HTML table.**

How do i achieve this?

```
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript> get() ;function get() { var method = "GetListItems";                
var webURL =  $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() ;                    
var list = "Core Libraries";                     
var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields>"+"<FieldRef Name='Name' />" +"</ViewFields>";
var query = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query>";                  

$().SPServices
({ operation: method, async: false, webURL: webURL, listName: list,
CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True' />",
CAMLQuery: query, completefunc: function (xData, Status)
{ $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function()
{ var title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
var update  =  $(this).attr("ows_Update");
var date  =  $(this).attr("ows_Date");

$("#myDataTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
"<td align='left'>"+date+"</td>" + "<td align='left'>"+update+"</td>" + "</tr>");

}); } }); };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `where` condition to your CAML query.

```
var value = "Cats";

var query = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Category' /><Value Type='Text'>" + value + "</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query>";
```

Comment: This is what i am looking for! Just 1 question, how can i do something like IF Cats is mentioned in the column, it will appear? e.g. Some columns will have 'Cats, mouse and birds' in a single field.

Comment: You should be able to switch out <eq> </eq> to <contains> </contains>!

Answer (score 0):

Make a new view and name it **Cats**.
Go in to the List settings>Create View.
Under Filter values, select Category equal to Cats.
Save, et voila...

Comment: No, i want my displayed HTML table to filter and to display all Cats. The code should go along the lines of CAMLQuery: IF Category=Cats, display Cats.

Comment: Sorry I missed that.  I don't know the answer, but someone else might already have posted an answer to a similar question.  Try searching through some of these Answers: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caml+query